# How to pass a string environment variable in postman/newman

Tags: postman

I have 2 chanined requests in postman, the first performs a GET to list all data, then sets an environment variable based on the returned values.
The second request attempts a POST using the environment variable as a field value.

**Request 1**

`GET /customers?$select=reference&$orderby=reference`

with tests:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var ref = 0;

for (i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) { 
    if (data[i].reference == ref.toString()){
        ref++;
        postman.setEnvironmentVariable("reference", ref);
    }
}
```

at this point the environment variable `reference` has the value 5

**Request 2**

`POST /customers`

with body:

```
{
    "reference": "{{reference}}",
    "name": "Name"
}
```

This works fine through the GUI of Postman, however when running from the command line Newman, when the request reaches the API, the value of `reference` is `{{reference}}` not `5` as expected.

I have performed the same type of substitution, with the environment variable set directly from the returned data

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('reference', data.reference);
```

and this work in either Postman or Newman.

Can someone help as to why the setting of the variable in a script block like this fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the setting of the environment variable, it was not being set.  The setting of this should have been outside of the for loop:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var ref = 0;

for (i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) { 
    if (data[i].reference == ref.toString()){
        ref++;
    }
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("reference", ref); // <--- This
```